# Installing eclim on osx 10.8.5 fails - no acceptable grep found

Tags: gcc, grep, installation, osx-mountain-lion, eclim

Im trying to install eclim on OSX 10.8.5 and the installer fails because it does not like the grep I have installed.

`[ANT][exec]configure: error: no acceptable grep could be found`

`[ANT][exec] checking for grep that handles long lines and -e...`

My grep has -e

```
SYNOPSIS
   grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
   grep [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using macports to install `gcc grep`. Apparently OSX now uses `bsd grep` by default and there are differences between the two that `gcc` was choking on. The part of this that a little ridiculous is that I installed gcc through XCode.